# Add feature to an OpenLayers VectorTileSource

Tags: openlayers, vector-tiles

Is there any way I could add a Feature to an OpenLayers VectorTileSource?
I know that the VectorSource has the method addFeatures() but not the VectorTileSource since it's of type MVT.

What I need to do is to get the Features existing in a VectorTileSource and add a dummy feature to the collection for a small test. If I could find a way of doing it would be great.

Comment: You may look at `tileLoadFunction` section https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_VectorTile-VectorTile.html It shows that you can read existing vector tiles (mvt) but also that you can `setFeatures` on tile level using GeoJSON tiles. By combining both approaches, you should be able to get existing features and add a mock one.

Comment: Yeah, the only thing is that I would like to do that to an existing vectorTileLayer.. In the function exemplified in the docs, I need to specify the URL, so it seems that will load a tile but it won't do it for the specific VectorTileLayer or its source, am I thinking correctly?

Comment: Just push your feature to the features array in the load function.  It can exist at all zoom levels and a polygon or linestring could cover several tiles, so add to them all.  You should use `featureClass: Feature` as you cannot easily create a `RenderFeature` https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-tile-info-forked-btv7j

Comment: Yes, however that example is on layer creation and I need to do it when the layer already exists cause I can't change the code that creates the layer.

Comment: I have updated the example to set the custom load function after creation then refresh the source https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-tile-info-forked-btv7j You will have a mix of Feature and RenderFeature which might cause problems' but it seems to work.